# How can i check if the file is empty?

Tags: python, python-3.x, overpass-api

I want to check if the json file is empty. Where in the code do i check that properly?
This is my code:

```py
import os
import sys
import traceback
import json
import requests
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

try:
    API_ENDPOINT = os.getenv('OVERPASS_API_ENDPOINT', 'http://overpass.osm.ch/api/interpreter')

    query = "".join(sys.stdin.readlines())
    r = requests.get(API_ENDPOINT, params={'data': query})
    print(json.dumps(r.json(), sort_keys=True, indent=2))
except Exception as e:
    print("Error: %s" % e, file=sys.stderr)
    print(traceback.format_exc(), file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Simple comparison with empty dict should do:

```
r.json() == {}
```

or

```
r.json() == dict()
```

or

```
len(r.json()) == 0
```

Edit: Seems like you may not be receiving a JSON in your response at all, to check that, you add this conditional:

```
if r.headers.get('content-type') == 'application/json':
    if r.json() == {}:
        # rest of your code
```

Comment: @ChristianNüssli please mark the answer as accepted to resolve the issue (click on tick mark)

Comment: Hi @Jarvis. Unfortunately every proposal you made didn't work with GH Actions. Any other solutions?

Comment: What is the expected and actual output after adding the conditional? What do you mean by GH Actions? @ChristianNüssli Check the edited answer.

Comment: GH Actions = Github Actions...
I try your last edit, one moment.

Comment: Seems like didn't work :(
try:
    API_ENDPOINT = os.getenv('OVERPASS_API_ENDPOINT', 'http://overpass.osm.ch/api/interpreter')
    query = "".join(sys.stdin.readlines())
    r = requests.get(API_ENDPOINT, params={'data': query})
    print(json.dumps(r.json(), sort_keys=True, indent=2))
    if r.headers.get('content-type') == 'application/json':
    if r.json() == {}:
except Exception as e:
    print("Error: %s" % e, file=sys.stderr)
    print(traceback.format_exc(), file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)

Comment: What are you trying to get as output? What is the expected and actual outcome?

Comment: @ChristianNüssli the conditionals I added should be checked for before you print your json.

Comment: I tried it, but the action fails again. I receive every time a json, but sometimes, of the API isn't answering properly, the json file is empty.